# PowerShell - Search a list of HashTables and filter them based on a key

Tags: powershell, list-comprehension

In Python you can do something like a list comprehension with a filter function to work through a list of dictionaries and find the ones you want:

```py
warranty_info = [warranty for warranty in warranty_info if
                                 args.warranty_keyword.lower() in warranty['ServiceLevelDescription'].lower()]
```

where warranty_info is a list of dictionaries and `ServiceLevelDescription` is a field on which I want to filter. The result is a new list of dictionaries with only those that I want. In this case I am looking for all the dictionaries who have a user provided word (`warranty_keyword`) in their `ServiceLevelDescription` field.

I know how to accomplish this in PowerShell using a foreach loop - is there a "cleaner" way to do it like Python has?

Comment: Isn't the python example you gave essentially a foreach loop?

Comment: Please share with us your definition of "cleanliness" :-)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - it's actually even more elegant than Python (Grant's opinion):

`$WarrantyInfo | Where-Object 'ServiceLevelDescription' -Match ^*pro*`

The syntax has a lot that's implied. This will search the list of HashTables and for each one extract the key `ServiceLevelDescription` - afterwards it will check if there is a match to whatever you put after the `-Match` switch.